# Angular-Resizable: Can't access attributes of "resizable"-directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to make a horizontally-resizable sidebar, which shall be resizable by dragging it's border to the left or right. Since the project I'm working on uses AngularJS I came across this custom directive (https://github.com/Reklino/angular-resizable) which seems to be quite popular with many users. The following lines are the relevant parts from my code, where I tried to implement it according to the instructions.

```
<div ng-app="angularResizable" class="col-md-5" id="main-sidebar" resizable r-directions="['left']"></div>
<script src="node_modules/angular-resizable/angular-resizable.min.js"></script>
```

My problem now is, that my IDE recognizes resizable (which probably means, that installation and integration worked correctly?) but I can't access the attribute "r-directions".

IntelliJ says: 
"Attribute r-directions is not allowed here...
Inspection info: This inspection highlights unknown HTML tag attributes as invalid, and lets mark such attributes as Custom to avoid highlighting them as invalid."

My AngularJS-version is 1.6.7 which shouldn't be a problem, since there are examples where it works with earlier and later versions.

Comment: Having details of the code you are trying to implement would be necesary to troubleshoot errors or actually see if your implementation is correct. In any case, you can use the codepen example from the authors of this plugin to get on track - https://codepen.io/Reklino/pen/EjKXqg